# Opening a bootstrap dropdown menu from an external button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, authentication

I'm working on a job where my employer wants a responsive website using Bootstrap 3 but they dont want anything visually changed on their existing desktop site (obviously not ideal but out of my control).

At the moment I'm working on the navigation portion. The issue that I'm running into is that I have a login form (a placeholder at this point) housed inside of a menu dropdown within the navigation. On mobile the form reamins in the dropdown but there is a seperate icon button added to the fixed top header bar title"Login" which is located near the hamburger menu and visible even when the main navigation is closed. Below is my codepen:

http://codepen.io/v_for_vinsanity/pen/YVGZdb

I'm looking for a way to get the login dropdown menu to open when I click the login icon button. Here is the code for the login dropdown menu:

```
<li class="dropdown login-dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle login-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300" alt="login-placeholder">
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```

Using jquery, Ive been able to get the focus to shift to the login dropdown menu (which you'll see in the codepen) but I havent been able to add the class of "open" to the li class="dropdown login-dropdown" and/or change the aria-expanded attribute to "true" on the Login anchor tag. Ive tried a number of different approaches but below you'll find what I currently have:

```
$(function(){
    $('.login-icon-btn').click(function(){
        $('.nav li.login-dropdown a').trigger('click');
        $('.nav li.login-dropdown').addClass('open');
        $('.login-btn').attr("aria-expanded","true");
    });
});
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would be an option

```
   $(function(){
        $('.login-icon-btn').click(function(){
            $('.navbar-toggle').click();
            $('.login-btn').click();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Richi Zee - Your solution works great the only issue is I need to use an if/else statement to determine if the slide out nav is already open which will determine whetehr or not to run $('.navbar-toggle').click();. But you have been a huge help Thank you so much!